# Send email with template (Mandrill JSON)

Tags: json, email, html-email, velocity, mandrill

Hi I've created an html email template using Apache Velocity . 
I'm trying to send email through Mandrill Json API. There is something known as html template in Mandrill.

But is there a way to send my html subject content generated by velocity to be passed as a String value to Mandrill and Mandrill would render the html to send email.

Please suggest any better alternatives to Mandrill (eg:Amazon SES, this is all I know of) as my system is developed in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [sendwithus](https://www.sendwithus.com). They provide a template management and sending API on top of Mandrill, and I know they support dynamic subject lines. [Docs here.](https://www.sendwithus.com/docs)